# What is friendUserId in Snapkit?

Tags: snapchat, snapkit

I'm connecting my app with bitmoji [here](https://kit.snapchat.com/docs/bitmoji-kit/#android), now i wanted to add Friendmoji also but In official documentation "friendUserId: the external ID of the friend user provided by the app" is mentioned but from where we get this external id is not properly specified! so what do i set for the friendUserId?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load external id when userIsLoggedIn. Like this way:

```
if (SnapLogin.isUserLoggedIn(this)) {
            loadExternalId();
        }

private void loadExternalId() {
        SnapLogin.fetchUserData(this, EXTERNAL_ID_QUERY, null, new FetchUserDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@Nullable UserDataResponse userDataResponse) {
                if (userDataResponse == null || userDataResponse.hasError()) {
                    return;
                }
                mMyExternalId = userDataResponse.getData().getMe().getExternalId();
                mFriendmojiToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(boolean isNetworkError, int statusCode) {
                // handle error
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i've already did it. This will load mine external id. Let me explain, when you call loadExternalId() then it will fetch user data and that data is of Loggedin user and loggedIn user is Me. But what i want is [check this](https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/bitmoji-kit#android) In which find for "Friendmoji" information. here they said to pass an external ID of another user as friendUserId, so my point is where to get that external id?